# Generate soft normals on sharp edges

Tags: normals

Does anyone know how to make your object render as smooth after using edge split modifier? I have to use edge split around all UV-islands (else UV maps get distorted in my game engine). However, besides splitting geometry it makes the edges render sharp there. Is there any way to preserve original normal data after using edge split?

Answer (score 1):

In **Blender** there is a way of editing the normals.

1. Duplicate the original object, before applying the edge split modifier.
2. Apply the edge split modifier.
3. Apply a **Normal Edit** modifier to the edge split object and select the original object in the **Target** field. Apply the modifier.

[image]

Comment: It starts storing normals in custom normal data which I can't get exported to my model file format. Any idea how I could possibly preserve original real normals?